# adding css fixed position on scroll, when element reaches top of window

Tags: jquery

I am trying to fix an element win scrollTop() reaches a certain value. This works fine, but the issue is that the element is part of a table, the table also exceeds the window width. The fixed element is the table header, but when I scroll x I need the "fixed" element to scroll with it too. I am not sure how this can be achieved. e.g. the window width might be only 1200, yet the table width could be 2000. Thus we are not seeing 800px of the fixed header.

Also when I scroll back up, the element remains fixed for some reason too, even though I am removing the class.

JQUERY

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    header = $('#header_worked').offset().top;
    win = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(win>header) $('#header_worked').addClass('fixed');
    if(win<header) $('#header_worked').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

Let me know any suggestions. I have it in [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6KWbv/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the margins when you scroll, so that the fixed element scrolls x with this code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    margin = $(window).scrollLeft();
    $('#header_worked').css('margin-left',-margin);
});
```

As for the add and remove class, the second condition to remove the class will not occur now, as the element is fixed. You will need to take another reference point of when you want it be relative again.